# Inheritance with template (accessing variable and object of parent class inside the subclass member function)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a very general question regarding the following error and I thank in advance for any helpful comment.  I simplified my coding to point out the error that I have received. (I got an error when I try to access object and variables of parent class inside the subclass member function.  I wrote the summary of error in the comment) Suppose I have the following code.

```
//here is the parent class
template<class T, int m, int n>
class A{
protected:
     vector<vector<T>> elements;
     int nrow;
     int ncol;
public:
    A();
}

A<T,m,n>::A():nrow(m),ncol(n){
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
    vector<T> row(ncol, 0);
    elements.push_back(row);
}//this is a constructor to assign MxN zero matrix 

//here is the child class and member function assign() and pow()
template<class T, int n>
class B:public A<T,n,n>{
    B();
    B<T,n> assign();
} 

template<class T, int n>
B<T, n>::B() : A<T, n, n>(){}//a constructor of child class for NxN square matrix

template<class T, int n>
B<T,n> B<T,n>::assign(){
    A<T,n,2*n> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j){
        //this causes error saying that "Error 1 error C2248:'A<T,3,3>::elements' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A<T,3,3>'"
        a.elements[i][j] = elements[i][j];
    }
}
    b.elements[0][0] = a.elements[0][0];
    return b;
}
```

If my coding is not sufficient to answer my question.  I can provide full details.  My ultimate goal is to make Nx2N matrix.a and put the elements of NxN matrix into the the left half of matrix.a and do some computations inside the member function assign(). (Or is that even possible?????) In main.cpp, I called 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't "simplify your coding" far enough. You can trivially reproduce your compilation error using a much shorter example:

```
class A {

protected:

    int n=0;
};

class B : public A {

public:

    B()
    {
        n=4;

        A a;

        a.n=n;
    }
};
```

This will result in the same compilation error as your complicated template code.

It is true that `A` makes its members available as a protected access class. All this means that the subclass `B` that inherits from `A` has access to its superclass's protected variables. But it doesn't mean that the subclass `B` can access another `A` instance's protected variables.

This is your fundamental issue. It doesn't really have to do with the specific details of your matrix manipulations, or anything related to that. It comes down to the way that inheritance, and public/protected/private access works. You just need to redesign your classes in order to make it possible for you to implement what you're trying to accomplish.

And this is another example of gcc's error message being much more readable than Microsoft's compiler (as this is what you appear to be using). Compare gcc's easily to understand diagnostic:

```
t.C: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
t.C:5:8: error: ‘int A::n’ is protected
  int n=0;
        ^
t.C:18:5: error: within this context
   a.n=n;
     ^
```

with the cryptic diagnostic from your compiler. The "within this context" part clearly points not just to the offending statement, but to the specific reference, "a.n", that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!!  So in order to fix the problem, do I have redesign whole class structure?  Is there any way to achieve my goal with inheritance?

Comment: "Redesign" doesn't mean "don't use inheritance". You just need to define and implement additional methods, in the superclass and the subclass, with appropriate levels of access, that allow you to do what you want to do.